# Magento 2 Coupon code restriction

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, coupon-codes, magento-cloud

I'm trying to modify the coupon code scenario and below is the scenario that I need to achieve.

- Full cart total should be >= $499.
- I added the condition that if a configurable product is found in the cart then a coupon code should be applied with a 100% discount.
- There are three products available in the cart as below.
- Product A has a price of $300 X 2 qty
- Product B is a configurable with 2 different options (ex: Red($50 for 1 qty) & Black($70 for 1 qty) )
- Total 3 Products are available in cart Product A with $600 price and Product B with two different options and each option has 3 qty.
- Here coupon code is applied as Product B configurable product found in the cart and below total is applied currently.
- Product A ($600) + Product B-Red ($50x3 = $150) + Product B-Black
  ($70x3 = $210) = $960 - ($50+$70 = $120 discount) = Final total is $840.

But here is what I need is that If multiple options are available in the cart for this configurable product that only higher options price should be discounted so the total should be as below.

**Total $960 - $70 discount = Final total should be $890**

If anyone helps me with this that would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.